# How do I make the validation type of number using react hook form version 7?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-hooks, typeof

I have used material-UI component TextField as input. The error message is showing even when I type in numbers.

```
<TextField
      {...register("salary", {
        required: true,
        validate: (value) => typeof value === "number" || "salary must be in numbers",

        valueAsNumber: true,
      })}
      label="Salary"
      variant="outlined"
/>

{errors.salary && <p>{errors.salary.message}</p>}
```

Comment: What exact do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: The error message is showing even when I type in numbers.